# Why do I get this error: "logits and labels must have the same first dimension"?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm using two arrays with the shape of `(1, 5)` so I used  `layers.Input(shape=(5,)),` but in the output I get this error:

> Node:
> 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits'
> logits and labels must have the same first dimension, got logits shape
> [1,5] and labels shape [5]     [[{{node
> sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits}}]]
> [Op:__inference_train_function_31405]

In my code I don't know what labels and logits are, so I can't solve this error.

Why do I get this error?

code:

```
x=[[1,2,3,4,5]]
y=[[3,2,3,6,5]]
x=numpy.array(x)
y=numpy.array(y)

model = keras.Sequential(
    [
        layers.Input(shape=(5,)),
        layers.Dense(3, activation="relu", name="layer1"),
        layers.Dense(3, activation="relu", name="layer2"),
        layers.Dense(3, name="layer3"),
    ]
)

model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=.0001),loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
    
model.fit(x,y,batch_size=10,epochs=11,verbose=2)
```

Comment: Logits shape should be `(5, 1)` with labels `(5,)`, probably.

Comment: "In my code I don't know what labels and logits are" Welcome to Stack Overflow. Is the question about what these terms mean? Or is it about how they relate to the code? Or something else? If you want to know what the terms mean, [did you try](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) using a search engine to figure it out? If it's about the code, does the documentation help? Have you tried following a tutorial?

Comment: @Karl Knechtel
I get a lot of errors in these things, can you provide a link to understand these things?

Comment: Please read [ask]. This is **not a discussion forum**; a *specific* question is required.

Answer (score 0):

logits shape is the output shape, which is the shape of the last layer (1,n_classes).

So:
x should be like (n_samples,n_features)
y should be like (n_samples,1)

In your case,

I suppose here n_features=5, n_samples=4, n_classes=7, so I added some examples here.

```
x=[
   [1,2,3,4,5],
   [1,2,3,9,5],
   [1,2,7,4,5],
   [1,1,3,4,5],
  ]
y=[[3],[2],[3],[6]]
x=numpy.array(x)
y=numpy.array(y)

model = keras.Sequential(
    [
        layers.Input(shape=(5,)),
        layers.Dense(3, activation="relu", name="layer1"),
        layers.Dense(3, activation="relu", name="layer2"),
        layers.Dense(7, activation='softmax')
    ]
)

model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=.1),loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
    
model.fit(x,y,batch_size=10,epochs=101,verbose=2)
```